# How to refocus blurred image like this?

Tags: photo-editing, blur, focus

Ok so I looked this image editing from 9gag and I searched little bit but couldn't find any info about it.

The first looked like [this](https://comment-cdn.9gag.com/image?ref=9gag.com#https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/aBg5r2A/alzPl5Am_700w_0.jpg)

And then it was edited into [this](https://comment-cdn.9gag.com/image?ref=9gag.com#https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/agVrdn/aZlLN7R7_700w_0.jpg)

What program is this? Is it simple to use, like a converter and save the result, or is it a program that need editing skill (I have zero skill in photo editing)?

Comment: Refocusing is possible but it adds more noise. The mathemathical term is deconvolution and was developped to modern levels to fix the focus problems of hubble telescope. Many many image editirs have a deconvolving sharpen (such as photoshops smart sharpen)

Comment: Since it seems to work mainly on the face, i would say it's a AI program who can recognize face features and create a imaginary face based on the info of the blurred one (so this will be close to reality, but not reality). 

Some websites can generate that (search for Pulse for example) but i don't know one tool in particular to recommend.

Comment: Have you any method to exclude bad jokes such as actually you saw at first a blurred photo and then a version which contains in the middle a smoothly faded area of the original? Actually also working sharpeners exist. Try this site (needs an account, free testing is possible) https://vanceai.com/sharpen-ai/

Comment: @joojaa On linear math based  deblurring stops working if the image has got a heavy nonlinear mangling like a JPG gets in a phone camera. A badly focused RAW image with no overexposure can be recovered more successfully because one can make for ex. 16 bit deep TIF.

Comment: @user287001 Obviously JPEG artefacts are  a problem, but theres also tools for eleiminating those. These are images not scientfiic data so its allways worth trying

Answer (score 2):

There's a free site here that looks promising: https://imglarger.com/Retouch It uses AI for facial enhancement. No login is required. I have no links with the website or developers, just found it using a google search.

First I enlarged the original image using Photoshop to get this slightly larger image. You could also use any similar raster software such as GIMP (which is free).

[image]

Then ran it through the process, and here's the result.

[image]

Note that many of these AI face enhancement tools work by trying to create missing details using other facial samples. They aren't actually deblurring the image. Notice how the rest of the photo is still blurry, it's only working on the face. So what you're seeing is a simulation of a possible face, not reality. It seems like magic though. Cool!

Just for fun, I blurred the original quite severely before uploading, the result I got is quite funny. However, it demonstrates how it is simply making up a face. In this case, perhaps 20 years older, and a totally different person!

[image]

Comment: "It's been 20 years" :P

Comment: @Vikas - yes, time has not been kind to that child! LOL